# Listview repete o último registro inserido no SQLite em toda a lista

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Estou aprendendo a desenvolver mobile para Android usando Java e iniciei os estudos para persistir dados. Estava tudo bem até quando tento buscar os dados do SQLite e inserir numa listview: toda a lista fica com os valores do último dado inserido no SQLite. abaixo meu fragment que é acionado na criação do app e após inserção no banco:

```
public class Listar_Produtos extends Fragment {

bancoDAO dao;
ListView lista;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listar__produtos, container, false);

        dao = new bancoDAO(getContext());
        List<Produto> produtosLst = dao.ListarTodos();
        lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.LstView);
        ArrayAdapter<Produto> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Produto>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, produtosLst);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }


}
```

abaixo o método no banco:

```
public List<Produto> ListarTodos(){
    db = constructor.getReadableDatabase();
    sql = "select * from "+constructor.TABELA;
    List<Produto> produtosLst = new ArrayList<Produto>();

    cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    try{
        cursor.moveToFirst();
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++){
            //while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                Produto produto = new Produto();

                produto.set_id(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
                produto.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nome")));
                produto.setTipo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("tipo")));
                produto.setComp(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("comp")));
                produto.setLarg(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("larg")));
                produto.setPeso(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("peso")));
                produto.setValor(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("valor")));
                Log.i("Nome "+produto.getNome()+ " ", " ID = "+produto.get_id());
                produtosLst.add(produto);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        //}

    }finally {
        db.close();
    }
    int a = produtosLst.size();
    Log.i("Temos no banco ",+a+" inserções de produtos na tabela "+constructor.TABELA);
    return produtosLst;

}
```

Verifiquei no banco e no log que os dados no banco são diferentes

```
waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 6709 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/cabral.produto: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/cabral.produto: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/cabral.produto: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
I/Nome bil2:  ID = 1
I/Nome Lucas:  ID = 2
I/Nome Luciano:  ID = 3
I/Nome Creuza:  ID = 4
I/Nome Luana:  ID = 5
I/Temos no banco: 5 inserções de produtos na tabela produto
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xec44a4c0, tid 6741
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xec452400: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec452400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe84859f0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec452400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe84859f0)
```

Porém só fica assim :

[image: Imagem do emulador]

[image: conteúdo direto do SQLite do emulador]

Classe Produto:

```
public class Produto {
    public static int _id;
    public static String Nome;
    public static String Tipo;
    public static double Comp;
    public static double Larg;
    public static double Peso;
    public static double Valor;

    public static int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public static void set_id(int _id) {
        Produto._id = _id;
    }

    public static String getNome() {
        return Nome;
    }

    public static void setNome(String nome) {
        Nome = nome;
    }

    public static String getTipo() {
        return Tipo;
    }

    public static void setTipo(String tipo) {
        Tipo = tipo;
    }

    public static double getComp() {
        return Comp;
    }

    public static void setComp(double comp) {
        Comp = comp;
    }

    public static double getLarg() {
        return Larg;
    }

    public static void setLarg(double larg) {
        Larg = larg;
    }

    public static double getPeso() {
        return Peso;
    }

    public static void setPeso(double peso) {
        Peso = peso;
    }

    public static double getValor() {
        return Valor;
    }

    public static void setValor(double valor) {
        Valor = valor;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Nome "+Nome;
    }
}
```

Pessoal, será que isso tem algo com o modelo de lista padrão que estou usando?
Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Adiciona o código da classe Produto.

Comment: Adicionei a classe editando o post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A razão de todas as linhas apresentarem o mesmo valor deve-se aos campos da classe terem sido declarados *static*.

Um campo *static* tem o seu valor partilhado por todas as instâncias. Assim, quando ele é alterado, qualquer que seja a instância que o altera, essa alteração é reflectida em todas as outras.

A última alteração é feita quando é lido o último registo da tabela onde a coluna NOME tem o valor Luana, por isso todas as linhas apresentam o valor **Nome Luana**.

Campos estáticos só deverão representar "características" da classe e não da instância.

Por outro lado, campos que identificam uma determinada instância não deverão poder ser alterados após a instanciação, por isso não deverão ter métodos *set*.
Será o caso do **Id**  e eventualmente **Nome** e **Tipo**, cujos valores devem ser atribuídos no construtor.

Comment: Muito obrigado @ramaral, alterei todos os campos retirando o static e regerei os métodos get/set e deu certo.